# Monitoring other's activities

Tags: civimember, contacts

As an admin is there a way to see what other people have been doing on their accounts on the same civicrm database?

Comment: A little more specificity about what you're looking to find would be helpful, but in general, unless you enable logging in Civi (which can greatly increase the size and affect the performance of your db, FYI), you can usually only see _that_ a particular user modified a record, not what they specifically did.

Answer (score 1):

Most actions are saved as an `Activity` in CiviCRM. You can get all Activities through the `Advanced Search`:

1. Menu: `Search` > `Advanced Search`
2. For the search field `Display Results As` select `Activities`

Using all the other search criteria you can filter the kinds of activities you are interested in (e.g. Activities of a specific user).

Does this help? Or what kind of things are you looking for?